Animation is not displaying Godot 4 before queue free
I am trying to play the animation once the enemy enters the area 2d of my player. For some reason the queue free is activated and is not showing the dead animation. Any ideas?
func _on_area_2d_area_entered(area):
    _physics_process(false)
    if area.is_in_group("enemies"):
        $AnimatedSprite2D.play("dead")
        await ($AnimatedSprite2D.animation_finished)
        queue_free()

I would like to know ideas to get a timer or make sure the dead animation is being played and the _physics_process is being desactivated.

You tagged this with 2 different versions of godot.  If you are using godot4, don't tag godot3 as well.   And SHOUTY text is considered to be bad manners

use set_physics_process(false) not _physics_process(false) also check if the $AnimatedSprite2D path is correct and try using $AnimatedSprite2D.animation_finished.connect(queue_free) instead of await
